# Difference between adding RAILS_ENV before or after a rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, environment-variables, ruby-on-rails-4

What's the difference between adding a `RAILS_ENV` before or after a rake task?  Here are samples from my staging environments:

- Adding `RAILS_ENV` after rake task.

  This raised an error, and the reason for this is accepting `development` environment as by default and not taking `devutility` as the environment.

  ```
  $bundle exec rake -T RAILS_ENV=devutility
  $rake aborted!
  $cannot load such file -- rack/bug
  ```
- Adding `RAILS_ENV` before rake task

  This works and lists all the rake task available.

  ```
  $RAILS_ENV=devutility bundle exec rake -T 
  rake about                          # List versions of all Rails frameworks and the environment
  rake assets:clean                   # Remove compiled assets
  rake assets:precompile              # Compile all the assets named in config.assets.precompile
  rake bourbon:install[sass_path]     # Move files to the Rails assets directory
  rake ci                             # Continuous Integration build (simplecov-rcov and deploy)
  rake cucumber                       # Alias for cucumber:ok
  rake cucumber:all                   # Run all features
  rake cucumber:ok                    # Run features that should pass
  rake cucumber:rerun                 # Record failing features and run only them if any exist
  rake cucumber:wip                   # Run features that are being worked on
  rake db:create                      # Create the database from DATABASE_URL or config/database.yml for the current Rails.env (use db:create:all to create all dbs in the config)
  rake db:data:dump                  ....................
  ..............
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RAILS_ENV` is an environment variable that needs to be available **before** running your rake task.

When you do:

```
RAILS_ENV=devutility bundle exec rake -T
```

It has the same affect as:

```
export RAILS_ENV=devutility
bundle exec rake -T
```

`RAILS_ENV` is not an argument to `rake` as it may appear, it's part of the environment available to Ruby though it's `ENV` constant.

Comment: okay, but do you know why it behaves in a weird way when placed at the end of the rake task?

Comment: Yes, because you run the rake task and *then* set RAILS_ENV so it's not set at the time of running rake.